# how can i add numbers to list by how great the difference is between them?

Tags: python

hey beginner here and i have this homework assignment where i have a list and il give an example to make it easier to understand so lets take the list = [1,2,4,6,5,9] now if 4-2 > 2-1 add to a new list the numbers 1,2,4 and so 6-4 isn't grater than 4-2 so dont add 6 to the list and it goes on
here is the code i wrote

```
lst4 = [1, 2, 4, 7]  # Replace the assignment with other lists to test your code.

# Write the rest of the code for question 4 below here.
l=[]
for i in range(len(lst4)-2):
    if abs(lst4[i]-lst4[i+1]) >= abs(lst4[i+1]-lst4[i+2]):
        l.append(lst4[i])
        l.append(lst4[i+1])
    
print(l)
```

how can i make it work ?
the  correct list that should be printed is [1,2,4,9]
i get  an empty list

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful to keep a running counter that tracks what the current difference is between the last two elements in your list.

```
lst4 = [1, 2, 4, 7]


def ListCreator(listy):

  listy.sort()

  diff = listy[1] - listy[0]

  result = [listy[0], listy[1]]

  for i in range (2, len(listy)):
    if listy[i]-result[-1] > diff:
      result.append(listy[i])
      diff = result[-1] - result[-2]

  return result
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without functions?

Comment: Yes, just remove the function and leave the body without the return